# AngularJS , small trick

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I've got one question . Is there anybody how has idea how to invoke function in controller only for the first li object in ul when ul has a ng-repeat?

Lets say ive got function in my controller like:

```
var init = function () {
  var a = this;
};
```

And my ul repeater seams like lets say:

```
<ul ng-repeat="up in userpartners" ng-click="setSelected(this);">
       <li>
          {{up.id}}
       </li>
</ul>
```

And I want to invoke init function with parameter 'this' which will be first 'li' item. Only for the first li i want to set something.

Comment: @msohns how exactly to write it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<ul ng-repeat="up in userpartners" ng-init="init(up, $first);">
       <li>
          {{up}}
       </li>
</ul>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.init = function (item, isFirst) {
        if (isFirst) {
            alert(item);
        }
    };
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/10332/)

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) check if $index is zero or $first is true.

Answer (score 0):

But there's already a single `LI` inside your `UL`.

I believe you mean:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="up in userpartners" ng-init="$first && setSelected(up)">
    {{up.id}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul ng-init="setSelected(userpartners[0])">
  <li ng-repeat="up in userpartners">
    {{up.id}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

See the difference? We want to repeat the children, not the whole list.

Although I believe it wouldn't be a good practice to have this call on a view. I'd put it inside a controller, the call itself.